# Missing Jetty files

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I am currently making an app using Jetty. I think I am coming along nicely, but I am seeming to be missing a lot of libraries. I have tried `AbstractHandler`, `Connector`, and even just `Handler`. I used 3 commands to download my current libraries.

```
JETTY_VERSION=7.0.2.v20100331
wget -U none http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/$JETTY_VERSION/jetty-all-$JETTY_VERSION.jar
wget -U none http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
```

I might be using the Jetty 9 though.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 7.0.2 is extremely old and very outdated.

[Jetty 7 (and Jetty 8) are now EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  Don't use them.

Don't use `jetty-all`, its not meant for integrating with your application, its a tool purely designed for experimenting with jetty from a command line.  Something that is only used as a demonstration of embedded jetty in the documentation.

If you are integrating into your application, starting with Jetty 7, you should be grabbing the individual component jars and using them.

Why isn't jetty-all enough you say?  Well, the whole concept of jetty-all is misleading, it cannot have all of jetty, as that would produce a jar that cannot be used.  There are many components and modules for jetty, nearly 90% of them are optional, and there are many alternative implementations for core components depending on what you want to do. (there are multiple jsp implementations, 2 different protocol negotiation modules, jvm specific boot classpath jars, etc...)

Lastly, don't use `wget` against the central maven repository system. your risk getting your IP banned if you do it enough.  Even the effort to hide the wget user-agent with `-U none` isn't sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for telling me! Now I have a different one(downloaded before you told me.) but it is still giving me an error saying org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector is not a class. That is true, but it is an interface. And I know it is there because it says so in the javadoc. Also I did get the all version for 9.2.9.